# Python json load with global language support

Tags: python, json

Hi I tried to use the international language on my script.

But it was returning the encoded data type.

Here my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json

string ='{\"NAME\":\"ทะเลทอง แลปกุ้ง\",\"DESC\":\"Shop Descriptionอาหารกุ้ง วิตามิน แร่ธาตุ\",\"ADDRESS_LINE_1\":\"29/4หมู่13 บางแก้วซอย1 ต.บางขวัญอ.เมือง\"}'
print json.loads(string)
```

It was returning the below encoded format

```
{u'ADDRESS_LINE_1': u'29/4\u0e2b\u0e21\u0e39\u0e4813 \u0e1a\u0e32\u0e07\u0e41\u0e01\u0e49\u0e27\u0e0b\u0e2d\u0e221 \u0e15.\u0e1a\u0e32\u0e07\u0e02\u0e27\u0e31\u0e0d\u0e2d.\u0e40\u0e21\u0e37\u0e2d\u0e07', u'NAME': u'\u0e17\u0e30\u0e40\u0e25\u0e17\u0e2d\u0e07 \u0e41\u0e25\u0e1b\u0e01\u0e38\u0e49\u0e07', u'DESC': u'Shop Description\u0e2d\u0e32\u0e2b\u0e32\u0e23\u0e01\u0e38\u0e49\u0e07 \u0e27\u0e34\u0e15\u0e32\u0e21\u0e34\u0e19 \u0e41\u0e23\u0e48\u0e18\u0e32\u0e15\u0e38'}
```

This script should suppot all kind of languages like Thai, Tamil, Chineese etc..

Expected OutPut

```
 data = json.loads(string)
 print data['NAME']
```

this should print 'ทะเลทอง แลปกุ้ง'

Comment: Please detail the error.

Comment: Your code works as expected in `Python 3.5`

Comment: So it's not supported in python 2.7

Comment: What does `print data['NAME']` print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json

string ='{\"NAME\":\"ทะเลทอง แลปกุ้ง\",\"DESC\":\"Shop Descriptionอาหารกุ้ง วิตามิน แร่ธาตุ\",\"ADDRESS_LINE_1\":\"29/4หมู่13 บางแก้วซอย1 ต.บางขวัญอ.เมือง\"}'
print (json.loads(string))
```

out:

`{'DESC': 'Shop Descriptionอาหารกุ้ง วิตามิน แร่ธาตุ', 'ADDRESS_LINE_1': '29/4หมู่13 บางแก้วซอย1 ต.บางขวัญอ.เมือง', 'NAME': 'ทะเลทอง แลปกุ้ง'}`

Just use python3

Answer (score 1):

Your script works perfectly (as expected) provided you use it on a unicode capable terminal.

I use IDLE for Python 2.7.12 for win32 on a Windows 7 box and this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json

string ='{\"NAME\":\"ทะเลทอง แลปกุ้ง\",\"DESC\":\"Shop Descriptionอาหารกุ้ง วิตามิน แร่ธาตุ\",\"ADDRESS_LINE_1\":\"29/4หมู่13 บางแก้วซอย1 ต.บางขวัญอ.เมือง\"}'
data = json.loads(string)
print data
print data['NAME']
```

correctly displays:

```
{u'ADDRESS_LINE_1': u'29/4\u0e2b\u0e21\u0e39\u0e4813 \u0e1a\u0e32\u0e07\u0e41\u0e01\u0e49\u0e27\u0e0b\u0e2d\u0e221 \u0e15.\u0e1a\u0e32\u0e07\u0e02\u0e27\u0e31\u0e0d\u0e2d.\u0e40\u0e21\u0e37\u0e2d\u0e07', u'NAME': u'\u0e17\u0e30\u0e40\u0e25\u0e17\u0e2d\u0e07 \u0e41\u0e25\u0e1b\u0e01\u0e38\u0e49\u0e07', u'DESC': u'Shop Description\u0e2d\u0e32\u0e2b\u0e32\u0e23\u0e01\u0e38\u0e49\u0e07 \u0e27\u0e34\u0e15\u0e32\u0e21\u0e34\u0e19 \u0e41\u0e23\u0e48\u0e18\u0e32\u0e15\u0e38'}
ทะเลทอง แลปกุ้ง
```

Said differently it is not a Python problem but only a terminal configuration one.